# Nginx caching for too long

Tags: nginx, proxy, cache

I'm trying to configure Nginx as a simple caching proxy for DarkSky so I can stay under the 1000 per day limit. However, I'm having an issue wherein it seems to not be honouring the `proxy_cache_valid` directive whatsoever and is caching for much longer than it's told to. Here's my config file:

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    proxy_cache_path /var/apicache keys_zone=apicache:10m max_size=1g inactive=120m use_temp_path=off;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1m;
    proxy_cache_background_update off;
    proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;

    server {
        listen       8765;
        listen       [::]:8765;
        server_name  darksky;

        location /api {
                    proxy_pass https://api.darksky.net/forecast/<myapikey>;
                    proxy_cache apicache;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's something I'm doing wrong but can't for the life of me figure out what. `nginx -t` is happy so it's not a syntax issue.

Here's what the response headers from darksky look like:

```
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 23:06:50 GMT
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-authentication-time: 1ms
cache-control: max-age=3600
expires: Fri, 29 Mar 2019 00:06:50 +0000
x-forecast-api-calls: 104
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-response-time: 37.548ms
vary: Accept-Encoding
content-encoding: gzip
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

I don't see anything that would cause issue except maybe for the Cache-Control but I've disabled that in the Nginx config.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but it's odd your proxy is outside the server block. I call PHP using fastcgi (source file from [this page](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/resources/aws-tutorial/config-files/nginx/sites/php-and-wordpress.conf) under " Nginx Configuration for PHP and WordPress single site" ), I set caching headers inside the location.

Comment: @Tim It's valid that way; it just means those directives apply to every inner block unless overridden.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Ryan, is the problem the browser is caching the resource, or is Nginx caching the resource?

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm hitting nginx from curl so it's not browser caching. The first request takes a few seconds then all subsequent request are instant, even after they should be invalidated. I thought it might be possible that nginx is reloading asynchronously when it gets invalidated and just serves the old result for the first request after the time out but I've disabled that already.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I didn't read the documentation properly. I didn't realize the expires header overrides the regular cache limit. All I had to do was add `expires` to the `proxy_ignore_headers` directive.